# Is there a way to "anchor" two columns together such that all their entries remained lined up in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout

I'm working on a little side project to try and get familiar with React/Javascript by creating a little summary page for Pokemon.
The way it works currently is that there is a search box which allows you to input a Pokemon's name and upon hitting the "Search Pokemon" button, it will pull that Pokemon's data from the public [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/).
I've got a working version hosted over on [heroku](https://pokemon-stats-react-app-5c2342764749.herokuapp.com/) where you can try it out to see what I mean and my code is currently hosted on [github](https://github.com/CalNisson/pokemon-stats-react-app).

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is have the 6 stats that show up at the bottom (HP, Attack, etc.) line up with the corresponding value to the right. To make it more organized, I've separated the stat names from their values and lined them up side by side using two column objects within a row object.

However, if you load this up on a smaller screen, it does not interact as nicely. "Special Attack" and "Special Defense" wrap into a second line, while their corresponding values don't stay anchored next to them, causing all the values to look as though they're shifted upwards.

[Normal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBLGj.png)
[Squished View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QWMI.png)

To make the code a little nicer and not have each of the 6 stat values hard coded into it, I have them each populating through a function that maps them to an array object.

I imagine I could solve this issue somewhat by just manually inputting 6 row objects with each value next to each other, but is there a way I could implement this without compromising the current method of rendering them?

EDIT: Added the code segments below

```
  function genStatNames(poke_stats) {
    const arrayItems = poke_stats.map((stat) => <h3 className={stat.stat.name}>{stat.stat.name.toUpperCase().replace("-", " ")}:</h3>);
    return arrayItems;
  }

  function genStats(poke_stats) {
    const arrayItems = poke_stats.map((stat) => <h3>{stat.base_stat}</h3>);
    return arrayItems;
  }
```

```
<div className="StatSection">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="column">
            <div className="column1">
                <ul>{genStatNames(pokemon.stats)}</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column">
            <div className="column2">
                <ul>{genStats(pokemon.stats)}</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have provided sufficient information, but please at least post some [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it's easy to reproduce and identify and may help others easily resolve it.

Comment: Sorry about that! Added some code segments to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your exact code for generating the columns, it would be better if you could post the actual code you are referencing, but this sounds like a use case for [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

When iterating over your pokemon's stats you can create a parent div that contains two columns. This parent row could be defined as `display: flex` then you could align them so that if your stat names wrap to the next line the values would be centered with the wrapped text.

```
<div className="row" style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <span style={{marginRight: '8px'}}>some very long attribute name: </span>
  <span>65</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate the reply. I've gone and added the relevant code segments to my post so you can see how I had it set.
Effectively, within the row I had two columns, one for the stat names and the other for the stat values. Within those columns, I had array objects that set each of the html elements so that I didn't need to individually place each of the stats.